# Creating a temporary folder in tmp folder on OS X

Tags: c, macos

How can i create a temporary folder in tmp folder using C++ language.

I have 3 volumes. Leopard, Development and 10.6 (in Mac OS X) and I want to create a temp directory in current home directory.

Here is my code. I am confused about this line `char* tempdir = "/Volumes/Development/NewFolder.XXXXXX"`:

```
if (!mkdtemp(tempdir)) 

   fprintf(stderr, "Not able to create directory");
```

Comment: You need to indicate which platform you are developing on.  Also your title and question/tag conflict with each other... are you using C or C++?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a temporary directory in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18792489/608639)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under POSIX, you can use [`mkdtemp`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) to create a directory with a unique name. On Windows, use [`GetTempPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364992%28VS.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the name of the temp directory, then create a directory with a random name there.

Comment: Can't get simpler than this :)

Comment: @iSight, no problem, though what you used is not my nickname. One day, Cameron will feel my wrath.

Comment: This is my code but is showing an error. Actually, i have 3 volumes. Leopard, Development and 10.6 (in Mac OS X) and i want to create a temp directory in current home directory.

Here is my code,

// i am confused about this line
char* tempdir = "/Volumes/Development/NewFolder.XXXXXX";
 
 if (!mkdtemp(tempdir))
 {
 fprintf(stderr, "Not able to create directory");
 }

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [boost::Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) function: `create_directory( "temp" );`

This is very portable and will work under most operating systems.

[Boost can be downloaded here.](http://www.boost.org/users/download/)

Comment: +1...which is why OP needed to clarify which language is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Boost is an excellent choice, but one of the problems with boost is that you would probably be downloading a huge amount of sources - if all you need is the filesystem functionality this is a bit of an overkill. Try http://stlplus.sourceforge.net/stlplus3/docs/file_system.html

Also why don't you just use the good old system() function? The string argument to system of course would be platform dependent.

Arpan