# creating a temporary folder in tmp folder c language Mac OS X

Tags: c, macos

How can i create a temporary folder in /tmp directory.

Comment: I saw you already asked this question before -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3014769 -- You should've updated that question instead of posting it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [mkdtemp](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mkdtemp) function.

```
char *tmpdir;
strcpy (template, "/tmp/myprog.XXXXXX");
tmpdir = mkdtemp (template);

if (!tmpdir) {
    // Error out here
}

printf ("Temporary directory created : %s", tmpdir);
```

Comment: "The mkdtemp() function generates a uniquely-named temporary directory from template. The last six characters of template must be XXXXXX and these are replaced with a string that makes the directory name unique." -- the question didn't ask for these specifications

Comment: @Sev: nor discarded. The OP still can use `mkdir` if he doesn't care about unique naming. IMO, launching a process to only create a directory is kinda exaggerated.

Comment: would you update your example to assign the return value to a variable? We get the idea, but the OP might not (no disrespect here).
I find important to mention about `mkdir` too.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't change/improve other's answers yet, I'm writing one myself.

I'd use `stat` and `mkdir`. For example:

```
#include <errno.h> // for errno
#include <stdio.h> // for printf
#include <stdlib.h> // for EXIT_*
#include <string.h> // for strerror
#include <sys/stat.h> // for stat and mkdir

int main() {
    const char *mydir = "/tmp/mydir";
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(mydir, &st) == 0) {
        printf("%s already exists\n", mydir);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    if (mkdir(mydir, S_IRWXU|S_IRWXG) != 0) {
        printf("Error creating directory: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    printf("%s successfully created\n", mydir);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```