# How to create a temporary directory in C in Linux?

Tags: c, unix, glibc

I am trying to create a temporary directory to perform some operations in it and then delete the whole thing at the end. I use C language in a UNIX system, so I would like to have some compliance with this environment.

What is the best way to program this ?

**EDIT**
I really need a directory, not only a file. The small program is intended to try out if I can perform an `svn checkout` of a project. So, it should be able to create a full hierarchy of files and directories.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest to use the `mkdtemp()` function together with usual functions from the C API (`glibc`). Here is a full answer:

**EDIT**: The [answer from Nemanja Boric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18792520/717822) is unfortunately not usable in practice because the `rmdir()` function is only intended to remove an empty directory. Here is a full correct answer:

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#define  _XOPEN_SOURCE 500L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <ftw.h>

/* Call-back to the 'remove()' function called by nftw() */
static int
remove_callback(const char *pathname,
                __attribute__((unused)) const struct stat *sbuf,
                __attribute__((unused)) int type,
                __attribute__((unused)) struct FTW *ftwb)
{
  return remove (pathname);
}

int
main ()
{
  /* Create the temporary directory */
  char template[] = "/tmp/tmpdir.XXXXXX";
  char *tmp_dirname = mkdtemp (template);

  if (tmp_dirname == NULL)
  {
     perror ("tempdir: error: Could not create tmp directory");
     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Change directory */
  if (chdir (tmp_dirname) == -1)
  {
     perror ("tempdir: error: ");
     exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /******************************/
  /***** Do your stuff here *****/
  /******************************/

  /* Delete the temporary directory */
  if (nftw (tmp_dirname, remove_callback, FOPEN_MAX,
            FTW_DEPTH | FTW_MOUNT | FTW_PHYS) == -1)
    {
      perror("tempdir: error: ");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You should **always** check for the return value of the system calls.

Comment: What if `/tmp` doesn't exist, or is unusable?

Comment: @TimSchaeffer That's why I said that perror should check if the return value of the `mkdtemp` is NULL.

Comment: Using `system(rm -rf tmp)` is a) slow, b) non-safe in any sense c) it will screw your signals d) non-portable, ... You really should use `(n)ftw/remove` or `opendir`/`readdir`/`rmdir`/`unlink` to remove your tmp directory.

Comment: You should change the name of the `template` variable, since it is a reserved keyword in C++.

Answer (score 11):

You should use [mkdtemp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdtemp.html) function.

```
#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char template[] = "/tmp/tmpdir.XXXXXX";
        char *dir_name = mkdtemp(template);

        if(dir_name == NULL)
        {
                perror("mkdtemp failed: ");
                return 0;
        }

        /* Use it here */
        printf("%s", dir_name);



        /* Don't forget to delete the folder afterwards. */
        if(rmdir(dir_name) == -1)
        {
                perror("rmdir failed: ");
                return 0;
        }


        return 0;

}
```

Don't forget to delete the directory afterwards!

Comment: In fact, I had hard time to get it work. And, no example in sight. So, I decided to post my solution here in order to help the others.

Comment: Nice job, +1 from me!

Comment: @perror Here it works fine without it. gcc 4.7.3 and gcc 4.8.

Comment: @perror, Yup, you are right. I will edit my answer and I will give entire code here.

Comment: No quite. `rmdir` is known to remove only empty directories. Look at my solution for a complete answer.

Comment: @perror, yes, and technically should use `opendir`, `readdir`, `unlink` and `rmdir`, because there is no guarantee that `rm` executable will be available on your machine.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to leave the comment. Will do now.

Comment: One problem is that this function if not ANSI C like `tmpnam`.